# Git feature branches dependencies

Tags: git, dependencies

I looked at several possible solutions on the Internet, but I still can not get it in my head, how it can help in my situation.
We have a variation of git-flow: master branch, dev branch, each new feature is created in a separate branch from dev. The problem is that two developers working on one feature are dependent on each other's code.

Suppose this is a project for a microcontroller. One developer writes the system part, manages the memory. The second developer writes UI and does not touch the writing of system functions. It is most logical to assume that everyone should have their own feature branch.

However, both branches are cross-dependent on each other. To develop a feature, the UI developer needs to call the functions created by the first developer. To develop the functions, the first developer needs to test them on the resulting UI. In addition, developers must be constantly agreeing on what functions should be created and what signatures they should have - changes made by one developer are needed by the second developer almost instantly because of their close pair work.

Another example - web-dev with backend developer and frontend developer being dependent on each other changes.

How can this situation be resolved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Integration branch?**

I would imagine that a possible solution would be to create an integration branch where updates meet more often. If something breaks, anyone can fix it in their development branch and rebase/cherrypick to the integration branch.

They are also sometimes called "throwaway branches".

**Example**

Imagine a clean repository with last commit on the `dev` branch - `D`.

User F (frontend) creates its own branch `frontend-dev` on commit `D`.
So does the user B (backend) a branch `backend-dev` on same commit.

Each user develops its own parts in their respective branches and as they are private branches, everything is allowed, including force pushes. And nobody else should commit to their branch.

After some time, the branches may look like this:

```
D - F1 - F2 - F3 - F4 <frontend-dev)
 \
  \ B1 - B2 - B3 <backend-dev)
```

Once the user F or B needs to test how their work integrate with each other, they create a new branch `integration` from commit `D` and accumulate all commits from both respective branches on top of it:

```
D - F1 - F2 - F3 - F4 <frontend-dev)
|\
| \ B1 - B2 - B3 <backend-dev)
 \
  \ F1 - F2 - F3 - F4 - B1 - B2 - B3 <integration)
```

If the backed developer finds a bug, he may create a fix, commit it as a fixup commit (with `git commit --fixup`) on the integration branch and test:

```
D - F1 - F2 - F3 - F4 <frontend-dev)
|\
| \ B1 - B2 - B3 <backend-dev)
 \
  \ F1 - F2 - F3 - F4 - B1 - B2 - B3 - B2Fixup <integration)
```

Once the developer is happy, he/she may cherrypick all the work to his development branch:

```
D - F1 - F2 - F3 - F4 <frontend-dev)
|\
| \ B1 - B2 - B3 - B2Fixup <backend-dev)
 \
  \ F1 - F2 - F3 - F4 - B1 - B2 - B3 - B2Fixup <integration)
```

And possibly delete the `integration` branch. To clean up the repository, `git rebase --interactive --autosquash dev` may be used to achieve:

```
D - F1 - F2 - F3 - F4 <frontend-dev)
 \
  \ B1 - B2(withFixup) - B3 <backend-dev)
```

Comment: It is not very clear to me what is 'Integration branch' and what it is consist of. Can you expand your answer with some examples?

Comment: Just a note, the integration branch may stay for a longer time if the developers communicate such thing with each other. If some change happens in any of the `dev` branches, they might be rebased.

Comment: Also, collecting the commits with `rebase`, `cherrypick` or any other means may keep things straight-forward. But yes, you can use `merge` as well! I.e: `git checkout -b integration dev; git merge frontend-dev; git merge backend-dev`